# Accessing Parents attributes

Tags: c#, inheritance, eiffel

It might be a silly question, but i'm new to C#. I am wondering if there is a way to use directly parent's attributes in child class. I did a lot of Eiffel and when a class is inherited by one or more classes(cause yes Eiffel don't have interfaces you can inherit multiple classes).

Just like that exemple:(Eiffel langage)

Parent Class:

```
class Parent

features
    int id
    string lastName
```

Child Class:

```
class Child inherit

    PARENT

feature
    bool isChild
```

In that case, Child class already got access to id and lastName and can be set directly as part of Child attributes, don't have to create a Parent.

But so far i made this(C# langage):

Parent class:

```
public class Character
{
    Int32 Id;
    String name;
    List<String> images;

    public Character()
    {
        name = "";
        images = null;
    }

    public Character(string a_name, List<String> imagePaths)
    {
        name = a_name;
        images = imagePaths;
    }

    public Character(Int32 a_id, string a_name, List<String> imagePaths)
    {
        Id = a_id;
        name = a_name;
        images = imagePaths;
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class NPC : Character
{

    public bool isVender;

    public NPC()
    {
        Character character = new Character();
        isVender = false;
    }

    public NPC(string a_name, List<String> images)
    {
        Character caracter = new Character(a_name, images);
        isVender = false;
    }

    public NPC(string a_name, List<string> images, bool a_bool)
    {
        Character caracter = new Character(a_name, images);
        isVender = a_bool;
    }

}
```

So there is my question, is there a way to get acces directly to parent's attributes in C# just like Eiffel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the fields you want to use in child classes as `protected`. Learn more about protected visibility modifier [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bcd5672a.aspx).

```
public class Character
{
    protected Int32 Id;
    protected String name;
    protected List<String> images;

    public Character()
    {
        name = "";
        images = null;
    }

    public Character(string a_name, List<String> imagePaths)
    {
        name = a_name;
        images = imagePaths;
    }

    public Character(Int32 a_id, string a_name, List<String> imagePaths)
    {
        Id = a_id;
        name = a_name;
        images = imagePaths;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the protected fields in child classes.

Answer (score 0):

What you *really* seem to want is to use the base class's constructor to set the base class's fields, which  is a slightly different syntax in C#:

```
public class NPC : Character
{

    public bool isVender;

    public NPC() : base()
    {
        isVender = false;
    }

    public NPC(string a_name, List<String> images) : base(a_name, images)
    {
        isVender = false;
    }

    public NPC(string a_name, List<string> images, bool a_bool) : base(a_name, images)
    {
        isVender = a_bool;
    }

}
```

> is there a way to get acces directly to parent's attributes in C# just like Eiffel?

If you do not specify an accessibility for a class member, they are `private` by default, which means that they are only accessible within the class itself.  So the *simplest* change is to make them `protected`.

```
public class Character
{
    protected Int32 Id;
    protected String name;
    protected List<String> images;
```

A *better* solution may be to add `protected` properties on top of the fields, which will still protect the actual fields but allow inherited classes to change the behavior of the properties.